# How to use webpack dynamic imports for submodules?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, es6-modules, dynamic-import

Let's say I have a single file `<google-map>` component which has a template which has a `<widget>` component and a `<marker>` component.

If I dynamically import my `<google-map>` component it would look like this:

```
Vue.component(
    'google-map',
    () => import('@/components/maps/GoogleMapAsync.vue')
);
```

Now I know I will not be needing the marker or the widget components outside of the google map component.

So when my map component loads I would also like to import all of the imports that this file has, and even preferably all the way down to the bottom of that tree.

So my map, widget and marker component will all be split off into one chunk.

Is there a way to automate this in Webpack instead of continuously chaining promises or resolving promises from a `Promises.all` stack?

I guess one way would be to put all of the imports in the same chunk like so:

```
import(/* webpackChunkName: 'googlemap', '@/components/maps/GoogleMapAsync.vue')
```

And do this for each component I want to be part of the `googlemap` chunk, but this is still a lot of manual work for something that I hope can be automated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import webpack plugin that let you import using webpack chunks. Also make sure chunks are genenrated.

```js
// Webpack 
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].js'
  },

  rules: [{
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    options: {
      plugins: [require('babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import')]
    }
  }]


// Vue code
methods: {
    LoadMarker() {
     this.componentMarker = () => import (`./path`)
        // Vue.js < 2.5 .0 // .then(m=> m.default) ; 
        }
  }
```

```html
<component :is="componentMarker"></component>
```

Comment: I am already using this plugin. I am still forced to manually implement all my dynamic imports though. I would preferably dynamically import a component and generated a chunk for all of the imports that this component needs. All under the same chunk/name.

Comment: @Stephan-v can you tell me what is emitted by webpack? also if you can show me webpack config.